# Nginx DoT Gateway > Status 500

Tags: android, nginx, dns, private

I try to create a DoT Gateway with nginx. However, i get every time when i try to connect via Android private DNS a status 500 response.

My Nginx config looks like this:

```
stream {
    log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time $upstream_addr';

    upstream dns {
        server 8.8.8.8:53;
    }

    server {
        listen 853 ssl;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/dot-access.log basic;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/dot-error.log;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_timeout 4h;
        ssl_handshake_timeout 10s;
        proxy_pass dns;
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve the error with https://medium.com/@nykolas.z/troubleshooting-dns-over-tls-e7ca570b6337 and https://www.aaflalo.me/2019/03/dns-over-tls/. A test request with https://getdnsapi.net/query/ works fine and i get `"status": GETDNS_RESPSTATUS_GOOD`. In in */var/log/nginx/dot-access.log* i see

`185.49.141.27 [01/Oct/2021:11:59:57 +0200] TCP 200 56 130 0.210 8.8.8.8:53`

However, if i enter "my.domain.com" in Android private DNS settings, i get the error message "*Connection not possible*" and in */var/log/nginx/dot-access.log*

`84.33.44.28 [01/Oct/2021:11:55:01 +0200] TCP 500 0 0 0.131 -`

For me, this means that this setup basically works, however not with Android Private DNS. Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same setup and it worked until yesterday.
There seems to be an issue with Let's Encrypt certificates:
https://twitter.com/WatfordJC/status/1443611562028245005

The problem can be solved by adding --preferred-chain="ISRG Root X1" to your certbot request. I just force renewed my certificate and now it is working again.
Other users discussing the topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/Adguard/comments/pynis4/agh_android_private_dns_couldnt_connect/

Comment: It seems this `--preferred-chain="ISRG Root X1"` will not work here. Maybe the cerbot package for Debian is to old. It seems im on *0.31.0-1+deb10u1*. Im getting the error message `certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --preferred-chain ISRG Root X1`

For the time beeing, i have removed the last cert in fullchain.pem. This seems to work also. Many thx for the tip with certbot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this cipher suite to solve the problem

ssl_ciphers         "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256";

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35399392)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).